# Displaying Result in the MainWindow C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to display text from MainWindow.xaml.cs file in the MainWindow.xaml

The following code below from MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
                                        if (condition)
                                    {
                                        Debug.WriteLine("You don't have problem.");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Debug.WriteLine("There is a problem.");

                                        if (condition)
                                        {
                                            Debug.WriteLine("Problem definition 1.");
                                        }
                                        else if (condition)
                                        {
                                            Debug.WriteLine("Problem definition 2.");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Debug.WriteLine("Problem definition 3.");
                                        }
                                    }
```

I want to print these messages in the mainwindow.xaml. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

As you begin with WPF, I would highly recommend you to learn about binding, and MVVM.
Let's say for now, for your string, just Binding will be enough, MVVM will come later, it will be a good starting point :

In your model (MainWindow.xaml.cs), you may add the following :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private string myMessage = "This is my default value";
    public string MyMessage
    {
        get { return this.myMessage; }
        set { this.myMessage = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("MyMessage"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyMessage = "Welcome to Binding World";
    }
}
```

Then in your View (MainWindow.xaml) :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" Height="50" Width="100"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding MyMessage}"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course binding is not something obligatory, but as you are starting with XML, I strongly advise you to begin learn about it right now, it will be of very great help.
Just Google "Binding", "MVVM" for more informations. Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/) I used at my beginnings.